# Question about induction used in a proof

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

> If $p_0, ... p_n \in R^n$, then $[p_0, ..., p_m]$ the convex set spanned by these points (the intersection of all convex subsets of $R^n$ containing $\{p_0, ..., p_m\}$), is the set of all convex combinations of $p_0, ..., p_m$.

Let $S$ be the set of all convex combinations.  If $X$ is any convex set containing $\{p_0, ..., p_m\}$, we show that $S \subset X$ by induction on $m$. The case is obvious for $m=0$.  Let $m \gt 0$.  If $t_i \ge 0$ and $\sum t_i = 1$, is $p=\sum t_ip_i \in X$?  We may assume that $t_0 \neq 1$ (otherwise $p=p_0 \in X$); by induction,

$$q=(\frac{t_1}{1-t_0})p_1 + \dots + (\frac{t_m}{1-t_0})p_m \in X$$

so $p=t_0p_0 + (1-t_0)q \in X$, because $X$ is convex.

**How was $q$ found by induction on m?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should probably read "by induction hypothesis".

The statement that is being proven is

> for all $m$, for all $p_0, \dots, p_m$, 
>   every convex combination of $p_0, \dots, p_m$ is in $[p_0, \dots, p_m]$.

The argument is proving that a convex combination $p$ of the $m + 1$ elements $p_0, \dots, p_m$ is in $X$. The element $q$ is *defined* to be a certain convex combination of the $m$ elements $p_1, \dots, p_m$. That's one element fewer, so by induction hypothesis, $q \in X$. Then the argument continuous to show that $p \in X$, as desired.